# Error running updates: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease

Tags: 14.04, updates

When I update, I get this error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: Seuraavia allekirjoituksia ei voinut varmentaa koska julkista avainta ei ole saatavilla: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886 

W: Tiedoston http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages nouto ei onnistunut  404  Not Found

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Spotify has changed the keys. You can solve this problem by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
```

Refer the official [update](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Linux-users-important-update/td-p/1157534) and [installation](https://www.spotify.com/de/download/linux/) instructions.